# How to rotate text in ArcGIS by any chosen number of degrees?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, annotation, text

I want to add a textline to my map and rotate it by about 160 degrees, but when right-clicking the element and selecting rotate/flip there is only the option to rotate by 90 degrees (100 US degrees). Is there a (non-scripted) way to do this, or perhaps a simple workaround?

The short text shall be put near one of the edges of a polygon, but does not belong to a specific feature that I want to label. I suppose I could make a new feature class and draw a line along the edge of the polygon, and then label it, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Insert text > Properties > Angle 160

Answer (score 3):

with labels you can use an attribute value to define your rotation (but I think that you'll need Maplex for that)

With annotation, you can add the annotation editing toolbar, and rotate your annotation with the Edit annotation tool

> Click the Edit Annotation tool Edit Annotation on the Editor toolbar
> and select the annotation.
>
> Right-click and click Rotate Mode, or press
> the **R** key. The pointer changes to a rotate symbol.
>
> Click and drag the
> text to where you want it placed. The text rotates freely about the
> selection anchor. You can also press the **A** key to enter a specific
> angle for the rotation. You can change the rotate mode pivot point by
> dragging the selection anchor to another location. To rotate and snap
> the annotation to another annotation or feature, turn on the secondary
> selection anchor. Press the **S** key to toggle this secondary anchor
> point on and off. You can move the secondary anchor the same way you
> move the selection anchor. When you have positioned the text where you
> want it, right-click and click Finish Rotate Mode, or press the **R** key
> again

Answer (score 2):

As @radouxju says if you are using Arc10.1 or later you will have access to the [Maplex Labeling engine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000026000000) to label a feature.

Within the properties you can set the label rotation either as a fixed value or based on a field in the attribute table of your layer.

[image: Rotating labels]

This aticle will explain further:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000037000000